# Is it normal behaviour for python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In the latest Python (3.2):

```
>>> l = [{}]*2
>>> l[1]['key'] = 'value'
>>> l
[{'key': 'value'}, {'key': 'value'}]
```

I expected l to be `[{}, {'key': 'value'}]` after this operation. Is it normal behaviour or a bug?

Comment: What you do means that `l[0] is l[1]`

Comment: After nearly 20 years of development, the answer to "Is [this] normal behaviour for python?" is pretty much always "yes".

Comment: To clarify Jochen's comment, if you type `l[0] is l[1]` you will get `True`, meaning they're the same object.

Comment: @Dmitry Shachnev Study the data model (http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) and the execution model (http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) of Python

Comment: @Dmitry Shachnev You may be interested by the answer I wrote in the following thread : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203295/python-map-function-passing-by-reference-value/7204329#7204329)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normal. Try using `l = [{} for x in range(2)]` instead.

`[{}]*2` does not actually make 2 different dictionaries - it makes a list with two references to the same dictionary. Thus, updating that dictionary makes changes show up for both items in the list, because both items are actually the same dictionary, just referenced twice.

Answer (score 3):

`[{}]*2` doesn't result in a list with two dictionaries, it results in a list with the same dictionary twice. Use `[{} for x in range(2)]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the same result over on [Codepad](http://codepad.org) for v 2.5.1

```
import sys

print sys.version_info 

l = [{}]*2
l[1]['key'] = 'value'
print l
```